# Change to spot colour power not updating the lighting in the Shading or Rendering tab

Tags: shaders

In the *Shading* or *Rendering* tab, when I change the power of the spot light between 10000 W and 1000 W, the lighting does not change in real-time. https://i.imgur.com/YdixBbi.mp4

The rendered image in the Blender Render window does reflect the changes though.

Why do changes to the spot colour power not update the scene in real-time in the *Shading* or *Rendering* tab?

Answer (score 2):

The Shading tab uses *Material Preview* mode by default. In this mode, lighting is provided by a hidden HDRI (can be revealed by increasing *World Opacity*), and there are no direct light sources (your scene setup and lighting is disregarded). To get your direct lighting (point lights and whatnot) into the *Material Preview* (or Shading) tab, check the *Scene Lights* box in the Viewport Shading properties. Alternatively, you can Press Z in the viewport and switch to *Rendered preview* mode, which will accurately reflect your scene setup, lighting and all (and what will be ultimately rendered):

[image: Scene]

To answer your second question, the reason lights do not update in real time in the Rendering tab is because the Rendering tab only shows a copy of your last render - it does not update until you render again.

Comment: As I commented above, I'm not sure if "_Rendering_ tab" is the "Blender Render window" which is also mentioned in the question...

Comment: I thought he was referring to the  tab at the top called "Rendering" (between Animation and Compositing).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Especially now since I see the linked screenshot in his question which I didn't pay a lot of attention to earlier. I just had your screenshot in mind which was on the default _Layout_ tab, so I didn't really think about the others. So it's probably helpful for him to learn you don't always have to switch layouts to see certain shading modes.